# iPhone : Where can we get the information of index created in Sqlite table?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, sqlite

In my iPhone app, I have created index on Sqlite database table for some columns.

Now I want to look at the indexes I created.

Where will I be able to look at the indexes? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Terminal, you can open the database with:

```
sqlite3 my_database.sqlite
```

In the SQLite3 app, `.tables` will give you a list of all tables in your database and `.indices TABLENAME` will list all indexes for a given table.

You can also use any other SQLite GUI app that is capable of showing you your indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I use SQLite Database Browser. It can be used to open the database you have created. 
I think this is the link for their site : http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I use Lita, an Adobe Air App, has some good features.

http://bit.ly/esVUUS

Path to app's databases in the simulator is

/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/VERSION/Applications/UUID/Documents/